# Why does launching an app with Windows Task Scheduler require additional privileges?

Tags: .net, windows, task, scheduler

I have written and tested a C# application using Visual Studio 2013.  I've successfully deployed the application to a Windows 2008 R2 server and created a non-privileged AD domain account for the application to run under.  I've assigned file system and registry permissions to that non-privileged account and made it a member of the local Distributed COM Users group so it can access the resources needed for the program to execute.

While logged-in to the console as that non-privileged user, I can successfully run the application from a command box, from the Start menu or by double-clicking the executable.  All of these work just fine, there are no errors and no UAC prompt.  So, it appears that the non-privileged account has the correct permissions IF the application is launched conventionally.

When I try to run this task automatically from Task Scheduler using the same non-privileged account, it successfully starts, but then aborts with a .NET System.UnauthorizedAccessException in one routine.  I don't know exactly where the exception is thrown, but I think it's at a line where a COM object gets instantiated.

I have tried this with and without the Task Scheduler option "Run with highest privileges".  If the option is enabled, the applications runs just fine.  With that option disabled, the application fails as described above.  Both cases are using the same non-privileged account credentials.

I am aware that Task Scheduler will, by default, start applications asynchronously.  Early on, I did have to configure Task Scheduler using "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" as the application and  "/c myapp.exe" as command-line options.  Without that change, the program would throw an AppCrash immediately when launched.  I think I understand that issue and I'm OK with using that workaround, although it would be nice if Task Scheduler offered Sync and Async launch options.

The real question is: Why does launching the app through Task Scheduler require additional privileges as opposed to launching it conventionally?

Comment: Where in program startup does the exection get raised? Before Main() or when it tries to invoke something within the program after Main starts?

Comment: Selbie: Main calls several methods and then one called ProcessFiles().  Somewhere within ProcessFiles is where the COM object gets instantiated and I think that's what is throwing the exception.  Thanks!

Comment: Show the code where the exception is occurring....